# Case Statement using 2 different Fields

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I have a field called subject, and the data in the subject sometimes is NOA, what I want to do is when the Subject is NOA change the field Date to nothing, and if it's not NOA use the Date that's in the Date field.
I know this isn't correct, but something like this: SEE CODE

```
Case
 when subject not like 'NOA%' then date
  else ''
end as NOADATE
```

Answer (score 5):

Does this work for you?

```
Case
 when subject not like 'NOA%' then date
  else NULL
 end as NOADATE
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.